# Spring and Dynamic DataSource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

I have two database structures, example:

1- MAIN_DATABASE: USER PASSWORD

2: CUSTOMER DATABASE: CUSTOMER_A CUSTOMER_B CUSTOMER_C

I want to access the main database and after validating the data, redirect to the customer database.

I currently use spring and configure it in applicationContext.xml

Example:

```
<bean id = "encryptionPassword" class = "utils.EncryptionPasswordSpring" />
<bean id = "dataSource" class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method = "close">
<property name = "driverClass" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name = "user" value = "user" />
<property name = "password" value = "123456" />
<property name = "jdbcUrl" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb?useSSL = false" />
</bean>
```

Any example, suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below is my code for dynamic datasource with mybatis. one is main ds. another is read ds. Hope it useful to you.

1. use AbstractRoutingDataSource to define a DynamicDataSource

```java
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class DynamicDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected DataSource determineTargetDataSource() {
        return super.determineTargetDataSource();
    }
    
    /**
     */
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.getDataSourceKey();
    }
    
    /**
     * @param defaultDataSource
     */
    public void setDefaultDataSource(Object defaultDataSource) {
        super.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource);
    }
    
    /**
     * @param dataSources
     */
    public void setDataSources(Map<Object, Object> dataSources) {
        super.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);
        DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.addDataSourceKeys(dataSources.keySet());
    }

}
```

2. use ThreadLocal to switch datasource in context

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class DynamicDataSourceContextHolder {
    
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<String>() {
        /**
         make main as default ds
         */
        @Override
        protected String initialValue() {
            return "main";
        }
    };

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static List<Object> dataSourceKeys = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    /**
     * switch ds
     * 
     * @param key
     */
    public static void setDataSourceKey(String key) {
        contextHolder.set(key);
    }

    /**
     * get ds
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static String getDataSourceKey() {
        return contextHolder.get();
    }

    /**
     * reset ds
     */
    public static void clearDataSourceKey() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }

    /**
     * judge if ds existed
     * 
     * @param key 
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean containDataSourceKey(String key) {
        return dataSourceKeys.contains(key);
    }

    /**
     * add ds
     * 
     * @param keys
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean addDataSourceKeys(Collection<? extends Object> keys) {
        return dataSourceKeys.addAll(keys);
    }

}
```

3. inject different datasource via application.yml or application.properties

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Interceptor;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;


@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.main")
    public DataSource main() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
 
 
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.read")
    public DataSource read() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dynamicDataSource(
            @Qualifier("main") DataSource main,
            @Qualifier("read") DataSource read
            ) {

        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>(2);
        targetDataSources.put("main", main);
        targetDataSources.put("read", read);
        DynamicDataSource dynamicDataSource = new DynamicDataSource();
        dynamicDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(main); //default
        dynamicDataSource.setDataSources(targetDataSources);
        return dynamicDataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(
        @Qualifier("dynamicDataSource") DataSource dynamicDataSource)
            throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean bean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dynamicDataSource);
        bean.setMapperLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:mappings/**/*.xml"));
        
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "sqlSessionTemplate")
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate(
        @Qualifier("sqlSessionFactory") SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory)
            throws Exception {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        @Qualifier("dynamicDataSource") DataSource dynamicDataSource
    ) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dynamicDataSource);
    }
    
}
```

4. define an AOP to control which Dao method use which datasource. Dao is interface to access DB via mybatis.

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Order(-1)  
@Component
public class DynamicDataSourceAspect {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamicDataSourceAspect.class);

    

    private final String[] QUERY_PREFIX = { 
        "select","get","find","query","quickGet"
    };



    @Pointcut("execution( * com.biz.dao..*.*(..))")
    public void daoAspect() {
    }
    
    @Before("daoAspect()")
    public void beforeDao(JoinPoint point) {

        boolean isQueryMethod = isQueryMethod(point.getSignature().getName());
        if (isQueryMethod) {
            switchDataSource("read");
        }
    }

    @After("daoAspect()")
    public void afterDao(JoinPoint point) {
        restoreDataSource();
    }
        
    //===============================private method
    private void switchDataSource(String key) {
        if (!DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.containDataSourceKey(key)) {
            logger.debug("======>DataSource [{}] doesn't exist, use default DataSource [{}] " + key);
        } else {
            // switch ds
            DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.setDataSourceKey(key);
            logger.debug("======>Switch DataSource to " + DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.getDataSourceKey());
         }      
    }
    
    private void restoreDataSource() {
        // reset to default ds
        DynamicDataSourceContextHolder.clearDataSourceKey();
    }


    private boolean isQueryMethod(String methodName) {
        for (String prefix : QUERY_PREFIX) {
            if (methodName.startsWith(prefix)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure two beans with two different set of configs in app.props

For one configuration you can use this (beanName = dataSource1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

    @Value("${datasource1.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${datasource1.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${datasource1.url}")
    private String connection;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource1")
    @Primary
    public DataSource mainDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl(connection);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```